# does typescript support parametic polymorphism

Tags: typescript, functional-programming

Say I have the following code:

```
export interface Semigroup<A> {
  append: (x: A, y: A) => A;
}

const arraySemigroup: Semigroup<Array<any>> = {
  append: (x, y) => x.concat(y)
}
```

This is great apart from the `any` for the Array.

Is there a way, I could specify the generic type parameter for array?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you can do this with TypeScript 2.8's conditional types. Building on one of the examples they use in the release notes, I came up with this solution:

```
interface BoxedValue<T> {
  append: (x: T, y: T) => T;
};
interface BoxedArray<T> {
  append: (x: T, y: T) => T;
};
type Boxed<T> = T extends (infer U)[] ? BoxedArray<U> : BoxedValue<T>;

const boxedNumber: Boxed<number> = {
  append: (x: number, y: number): number => {
    return x + y
  }
}

const boxedNumberArray: Boxed<number[]> = {
  append: (x: number, y: number): number => {
    return x + y
  }
}
```

The release notes can be seen here: http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html They show the `Boxed` example but they don't use the `infer` feature in that example.